# Windows Server 2008 Run Printing With Specific Printer Always As Specific User

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-permissions, printing

I have the follow setup:

Windows Server 2008 SBS with an active spooler. I am using this server, besides other things, as a printing server.

I've shared a lot of printers and I've added a new one today, but there are some problems.

The printer is a virtual (pdf gui-less command line) printer, that I want to share over the network.
It reads his settings and commands out of information it founds in the documents to print. It does specific things like creating a pdf, mail the document to someone and archive the pdf on serveral locations, add overlays to the file, print it on physical printer and so on. I've tested it on a virtual machine and printing over the network works perfectly if the server is outside the domain. However, The live server is obviously inside the domain and now something strange happens:

When I send a print job from a client computer, it runs the process for the pdf creation as the user who executes the printing. Example:

Server User DOMAIN\Admin, document sending user: DOMAIN\us1 process starts up as us1 and hangs (I guess because of a hidden UAC message or something or the process can't find configurations for DOMAIN\us1 because the software was installed for DOMAIN\Admin).

I somehow have to get the process to run as DOMAIN\Admin (or any other specific user i can give the rights for the file manipulations) no matter who sends the printing job. If I log on the client computer as DOMAIN\Admin and then send the document to the shared printer everything works fine.

It has something to do with user restrictions, I know, but even if I grand administrative permission for all of the files/folders involved, it still stucks. And I can not attach the printer as a specific user, because the users have already established a net use connection with their network credentials, and two differents are not possible.

My question: I need to somehow to force the client, that he sends the printing requests as the DOMAIN\Admin user without password authentification or that the server executes the printing job for this printer only as a specific user (DOMAIN\Admin) no matter who send the request.

Any help?